# Extjs 4.1 Calendar bug - Click and hold event (not drag event)

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1

Example i have a event (1pm -> 3pm) like

[image]

When you Click and hold event (not drag event) like

[image]

And when u drop that then both `window edit` show and `event move` fire.

[image]

While the second picture show like the event will not move. How to fix that thanks

Comment: There is no click and hold event. The second image shows that there was a drag event fired. You see that icon in the tip ?

Comment: @LorenzMeyer No, b/c i can't capture cursor, `When you Click and hold event (not drag event) ` u can test this bug in http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.1/extjs-build/examples/calendar/index.html

Comment: Sorry, This example does not work with me (in Chrome), and I don't really understand the problem without looking at it live.

Comment: @LorenzMeyer here is my test in Chrome http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nvegkRkJwGM